# how can i get the string start with lowercase?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const arryStudent = [{
    name: 'faizan',
    rollNo: 11,
    marks: 80
  },
  {
    name: 'irfan',
    rollNo: 12,
    marks: 75
  },
  {
    name: 'Abdullah',
    rollNo: 13,
    marks: 69
  },
  {
    name: 'Asad',
    rollNo: 23,
    marks: 71
  },
  {
    name: 'ali',
    rollNo: 14,
    marks: 71
  }

];

const startsWithA = arryStudent.filter((student) => student.name.startsWith('A'));

console.log(startsWithA);
```

Comment: So you need to combine `startsWith` with `lowercase` or just `lowercase`?

Comment: So, you want a case insensitive filter?

Comment: startsWith lowercase

Comment: i want to get string also starts from lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startsWith` twice like:

```js
const arryStudent = [{
    name: 'faizan',
    rollNo: 11,
    marks: 80
  },
  {
    name: 'irfan',
    rollNo: 12,
    marks: 75
  },
  {
    name: 'Abdullah',
    rollNo: 13,
    marks: 69
  },
  {
    name: 'Asad',
    rollNo: 23,
    marks: 71
  },
  {
    name: 'ali',
    rollNo: 14,
    marks: 71
  }

];

const startsWithA = arryStudent.filter((student) => student.name.startsWith('A') || student.name.startsWith('a'));

console.log(startsWithA);
```

Comment: Thanks brother this was really helpfull..

Comment: You are welcome :) approve the question thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can check..

```
    arryStudent.forEach(element => {
        if (element.name[0] == element.name[0].toLowerCase()){
         console.log(`${element.name} startswith lower case`);
      }
        if (element.name[0] == element.name[0].toUpperCase()){
         console.log(`${element.name} startswith Upper case`);
      }

    });
```

Comment: the string i wants starts with the specific character as you see in my code.. but that  character is also in the lowercase form..  so how can i get both in a single filter method

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that filters out the names based on the letter.

```js
const students=[{name:"faizan",rollNo:11,marks:80},{name:"irfan",rollNo:12,marks:75},{name:"Abdullah",rollNo:13,marks:69},{name:"Asad",rollNo:23,marks:71},{name:"ali",rollNo:14,marks:71}];


// Write a function that accepts the data,
// and the letter you're looking for
function find(arr, letter) {

  // Always lowercase the letter
  const lc = letter.toLowerCase();
  
  // And then filter out the names that match
  return arr.filter(student => {
    return student
      .name
      .toLowerCase()
      .startsWith(lc);
  });

}

console.log(find(students, 'A'));
```

Comment: what about the uppercase strings?

Comment: What about them? Your question is "how can i get the string start with lowercase?".

Comment: the string i want starts with the same character but they are in different in cases .. lets say i want string starts with capital A.. but there's lowercase also.. so how can i get that too?

Comment: My update should help. @Faizan